# Call non-generic Method(Generic<Base>[] args) and pass array of Generic<Derived>?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Solution to call non-generic method and pass generic arguments with different generic types?

**My imaginary dream:**

```
void FooBulous(Foo<object>[] fooArray) {  } // Accept any 'Foo<BaseType>'

var fooArray = new Foo<object>[]    // Array of 'Foo<BaseType>'
{
  new Foo<Cat>(),
  new Foo<Dog>(),
};

FooBulous(fooArray); // Pass the 'Foo<BaseType>[]' array
```

**My reality:**

```
void BarBaric(object[] barArray) {  } // Can't constrain to 'Foo<>'

var barArray = new object[]  // Same problem
{
  new Bar<Cat>(),
  new Bar<Dog>(),
};

BarBaric(barArray); // Barbaric! I thought the 'void *ptr' days were over!
```

**In summary:**

```
void Fee(object[] params)      { /* WORKS! But not constrained to 'Foo<Base>' */ }
void Fie(Foo<Cat>[] params)    { /* Does not accept 'Foo<Dog>' */ }
void Foe(Foo<>[] params)       { /* ERROR: 'Type expected' */ }
void Fum(Foo<object>[] params) { /* Cannot convert 'Foo<Cat>' to 'Foo<object>' */ }
```

**Clearly, this can't be done... Is there a clean alternative?**

Comment: There's probably an *unclean* alternative involving abuse of `dynamic`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that a `Foo<Cat>` isn't a `Foo<object>`. Suppose `Foo` looked like this:

```
public class Foo<T>
{
    public void Method(T input)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Then a `Foo<Cat>` would always expect a `Cat` value for the `input` parameter to `Method`. But if you could treat `Foo<Cat>` as a `Foo<object>` you could do:

```
Foo<Cat> catFoo = new Foo<Cat>();
Foo<object> objectFoo = catFoo;
objectFoo.Method(new object()); // Eek! Type safety is broken!
```

Now *generic variance* is available in .NET 4 (and C# 4) but *only* for interfaces and delegates, and *only* for those decorated appropriate with `out` and `in` at the point of the type parameter declaration. That may or may not be useful to you.

Another option is to make `Foo<T>` derive from an abstract non-generic base class `Foo` which provides all the members which have nothing to do with `T`. Then you could write:

```
void Foobulous(Foo[] fooArray)

...

Foobulous(new Foo[] {
    new Foo<object>(),
    new Foo<Cat>(),
    new Foo<Dog>()
});
```

and all would be well, so long as `Foobulous` didn't need to use any of the methods which relied on `T` - which it shouldn't, given that it can take `Foo` values with different type parameters anyway.

Comment: Truly, I could have left the method call out of the question: If an array can be created (as you demonstrated), then it can be passed to a method.

Comment: @Jon Skeet `Foo<>` is an Entity Framework `DbSet<>`, which is a `DbQuery<>`, which is... an `object`. So, I'm stuck with `object[]` unless there is a clever refactoring.

Comment: @Kevin: But the array has to be *useful* - you can create an `object[]` as you've already seen :)

Comment: @Kevin: Ah... right, if you can't give it a non-generic base class/interface, there's not a lot you can do, I'm afraid :(

Comment: @Jon Skeet I will look into the delegate thing. Actually, I think I'm doing that already--- In my method `Foo<>[]` is iterated to call `XElement ToXml<TEntity>(DbSet<TEntity> dbSet)` which converts the entity set to XML. My method uses reflection to create a `Func<DbSet<object>, XElement>` using `MethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(TEntity))`. That's a "delegate" right? (What do I know... I'm just a dumb fireman trying to write good code for fun on my days off.) Passing in something "cleaner" than `object` (type constrained to `DbSet<>`) was the goal. MUCHO GRACIAS!

Comment: @Kevin: The `Func<,>` is a delegate, yes... but `DbQuery<T>` and `DbSet<T>` aren't.

Comment: @Jon Skeet Do you own a time machine? You answered that in 4 minutes (read Q/contemplate/type response)... Envy. :) Cheers.