# Unable to add a generic concrete type to a list of generic interface

Tags: c#, list, generics, interface, conceptual

**Background:**

I am trying to create a list that can store different types/implementations of people. This list will then be filtered and operated on based on what type of person they are, and what data source their information has come from.

**This is what is failing:**

When attempting to add my concrete types to my list that is typed against my interface, it is failing convertion and unable to perform casts to (see below), regardless of the type constraint on my generic.

```
var people = new List<Person<IPerson>>();

people.Add(new Person<Student>()); // Compile error: Cannot convert from Person<Student> to Person<IPerson> 
people.Add(new Person<StaffMember>() as Person<IPerson>); from Person<StaffMember> to Person<IPerson> via reference conversion, boxing, unboxing etc.
```

If I update my list to ignore the "wrapper" `Person<>` generic type and just store the list of people types, it looks like this is valid. So something is clearly wrong with my assumptions around the generic side of things!

```
var people = new List<IPerson>();

people.Add(new Student()); // This is valid (at least at compile time)
people.Add(new StaffMember()); // This is valid (at least at compile time)
```

**Current implementation:**

```
public interface IPerson
{ }

public class Person<TPerson> where TPerson : IPerson
{
    // Various common props here...
    public DataSource Source { get; set; }

    // My generic prop
    public TPerson Record { get; set; } 
}

public class Student : IPerson
{
    // Student specific props
}

public class StaffMember : IPerson
{
    // Staff member specific props
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What even is the purpose of your `Person<T>` type?

Comment: Just because `A` and `B` exhibit a particular inheritance or implementation relationship, that *doesn't* mean that `G<A>` and `G<B>` will exhibit the *same* relationship. There are some exceptions for variant interfaces and delegates, but not for concrete generic types.

Comment: And most notably, - if you could do what you tried to do, this would also compile - `((Person<IPerson>)new Person<Student>()).Record = new StaffMember()` and your real, actual, `Person<Student>` object has been assigned a reference to a non-student.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Call non-generic Method(Generic<Base>\[\] args) and pass array of Generic<Derived>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6616017/call-non-generic-methodgenericbase-args-and-pass-array-of-genericderived)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `Person<T>` to be assignable to `Person<IPerson>` the type needs to be [Covariant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/), and you need an interface to make covariant:

```
public interface IPerson { }
public interface IPerson<out T> {
    T Record { get; } // setter not allowed
 }

public class Person<TPerson> : IPerson<TPerson> where TPerson : IPerson
{
    // My generic prop
    public TPerson Record { get; set; }
}
public class Student : IPerson { }
...
var list = new List<IPerson<IPerson>>();
list.Add(new Person<Student>()); // works
```

This covariance will place some limits on how the `TPerson` can be used in the `IPerson<T>` interface. A property like `T Record { get; }` is fine, since you are returning a type T, and all such types are an `IPerson`. A method like `void MyMethod(T value)` is not fine, since it would allow calling a method on `Person<Student>` object with a `StaffMember` object, and that is not allowed.

But do consider if you need to use generics in the first place, and if you do, consider naming. `Person<IPerson>` or `IPerson<IPerson>` can easily be confusing.

Comment: Thanks for the info - I'll do some reading around covariants! In the meantime, it looks like your suggestion still suffers from the same conversion issue when trying to add to the list.

Comment: @Tomuke `Person<Student>` should be implicitly convertible to `IPerson<IPerson>`. The same is not true for conversions to `Person<IPerson>`, so check that you are using the interface.

Comment: Ahhh yes, I see! That looks to have solved it for me! Need to take some time to understand this properly! Thank you!

Comment: do you know how I can acheive a similar thing, but this time with a closed constructed type? E.g. If I have `public interface IPersonHandler<TPersonType> where TPersonType : IPerson` and then have my various closed constructed types of `StaffHandler : IPersonHandler<StaffMember>` and `StudentHandler : IPersonHandler<StaffMember>`. Then trying to add these to a common list of `List<IPersonHandler<IPerson>>`

Comment: @Tomuke I don't really see how that is any different, as long as you can declare your TPersonType as covariant.

Answer (score 0):

> So something is clearly wrong with my assumptions around the generic side of things!

That would seem to be the case although I'm not clear on what your assumptions are.

Generics don't support composing types. If your assumption is that an instance of a `Person<Student>` would have the members of `Student` and the members of `Person<T>`, that is not correct.

Generics are sometimes called 'templates' and I think that name is useful in understanding generics.

In an abstract sense, what does a list provide? Add? Remove? Index? If you had to write a list for every type, the code would not vary much. The implementation of a List of `Student` and a list of `StaffMember` would be the same except for the type used. `List<T>` is a generic type. The implementation is written in terms of `T` and not a specific type. It can be thought of as a template for creating a list of any type.

You can't have a heterogeneous collection. If you use an `ArrayList`, everything from the perspective of the collection is an `object`. If you use a `List<T>` everything is whatever you specified for `T`.

If you define a `List<IPerson>` you can add any object that implements (or 'is a') `IPerson`. If the `IPerson` interface has a `Name` property, you can get the `Name` from any `IPerson` regardless of whether it is a `Student` or `StaffMember`.

`List<IPerson>`, `List<Student>`, and `List<StaffMember>` are different unique types. You cannot add a `StaffMember` to a `List<Student>`.

Your wrapper class could be written as follows and used with a `List<Person>`.

```cs
public class Person
{
    public Person(IPerson person)
    {
        Record = person;
        ...
    }

    public DataSource Source { get; set; }

    public IPerson Record { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I would not conflate c# 'generics' with c++ 'templates'. While they use a similar syntax they work very differently under the hood.

Comment: Yes, C# generics and C++ templates are not the same especially "under the hood". I didn't mention C++. However, I think there is no debate that C++ templates inspired generics in Java, C#, and other languages.

Comment: My point is that 'template' is strongly associated with c++. And using that term may lead anyone knowledgeable about C++ to incorrect conclusions. Especially since there are also 'T4 text templates' that is a completely different thing. So I think using the term 'Template' does more harm than good when discussing generics.